# How to get the pk of the selected radio button in django

Tags: django

I'm having a hard time trying to learn Django :)

I have the following line (which might not be in the best form but they work so far):

models.py

```
class Mani(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
description = models.TextField()
duration = models.ForeignKey(Duration, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
price = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s kostet €%s und dauert %s min" % (self.title, self.description, self.price, self.duration.duration)
```

forms.py

```
class ManiForm(forms.Form):
service_title = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'class': 'serviceForm'}), label='Bitte whälen Sie Ihre Packet', queryset=Mani.objects.all())
```

views.py

```
def booking_service_detail(request, pk):
service = Service.objects.get(pk=pk)

if request.method == 'POST':
    service_form = ManiForm(request.POST)
    mani = Mani.objects.get(pk=pk)
    
    return render(request, template, {
    'service': service,
    'service_form': service_form,
    'extra_form': extra_form,
    'mani': mani
})
    
mani = Mani.objects.all()
service_form = ManiForm()
context = {
    'service': service,
    'service_form': service_form,
}
return render(request, template, context)
```

and finaly part of the html:

```
<div class="content">
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <h3>Bitte whälen Sie Ihre Packet</h3>
    <ul class="serviceForm">
        {% for radio in service_form.service_title %}
        <li>
            {{ radio }}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% if extra_form %}
    <h4>Bitte whälen Sie Ihre Extra</h4>
    <p>{{ mani.pk }}</p>
    <ul class="serviceForm">
        {% for radio in extra_form.extra_title %}
        <li>
            {{ radio }}
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    <input type="submit" value="Auswählen">
</form>
```

One of the li items from here:

```
{% for radio in service_form.service_title %}
    <li>
        {{ radio }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

get's an atribute of checked after I press the submit button and the second form appears. I want to filter the items that appear from the second form based on the value of the checked item from the first form.
[HTML interpretation of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ElGO.png)

How can I get the value of the checked item in my views.py?

Comment: Where is your code of extra_form?

Comment: The code for the extra_form is the second ul in the HTML and in view.py it's inside if request.method == 'POST'

Comment: You can simple do `service_form.cleaned_data['service_title']`. See my answer. is it what you want?

Comment: How do you define "extra_form"? Which fields does your "extra_form" contain? Share your code

Comment: Thank you NKSM, your suggestion helped me alot and now I managed to get everything working :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your value from `request.POST` or `form.cleaned_data`

See also [Accessing “clean” data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data)

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    service_form = ManiForm(request.POST)
    mani = Mani.objects.get(pk=pk)

    service_title = service_form.cleaned_data['service_title']

    extra_form.fields['extra_title'].queryset = ...filter your objects by service_title here...
    
    return render(request, template, {
        'service': service,
        'service_form': service_form,
        'extra_form': extra_form,
        'mani': mani
    })
```

Or in template

```
{% for choice in extra_form.extra_title.field.queryset %}
    {% if choice.mani.pk == mani.pk %}
        {{ choice.pk }} - {{ choice.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```